# reference a class by variable, perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am writing an IRC bot with plugin modules. There is a SQLite DB which stores command definitions.

I will have a module `Bot::Plugins::Modes` and it will have methods like `kick` and `voice`. I instantiate `Modes` like so:

```
$modes = new Bot::Plugins::Modes
```

And I can call a method like so:

```
$modes->voice(arg1 arg2);
```

In my database I have fields `module` and `method`. For this example the module and method are `modes` and `voice`, respectively.

The listener that listens for bot commands executes them. I am trying to do something like...

```
&{"$module->$method"}(arg1, arg2)
```

But I cannot figure out the syntax. Before they were loadable via module and were just subs I could do:

```
&{$command}(arg1, arg2)
```

Where `$command` is the method field from the database. In this case it was just "voice", and `voice` is a subroutine.

Answer (score 4):

Both the class and method name can be a scalar.  The rest of the syntax is normal.

```
my $module = "Foo";
my $method = "bar";

# Same as Foo->bar($arg1, $arg2);
$module->$method($arg1, $arg2);
```

Comment: he should avoid using 'use strict' for the lexical scope of this calling, or at least use 'no strict 'refs'', isnt it?

Comment: It's not a symbolic reference, so it's perfectly fine under `use strict`. You're probably thinking of symbol table shenanigans, like `&{ $package . "::$method" }` - that does require `strict refs` to be turned off.

Answer (score 3):

```
$module->$method(arg1, arg2);
```

Also, [`UNIVERSAL::can`](http://perldoc.perl.org/UNIVERSAL.html) if you want to check whether a method exists before calling it.

```
$sub = $module->can($method);
if ($sub) {
    &$sub($module, arg1, arg2);
}
```

(Calling `&$sub(arg1, arg2)` would be like invoking `package::method(arg1, arg2)`, not `package->method(arg1, arg2)`.)